# BigQuery - Incompatible Type at UNION ALL?

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is a simplified version of my query.  DebugReason in the Debug table is of type `INTEGER` and DebugData is of type `STRING`. And There's no such two fields in GPS table so I faked it with all `NULL`. Reason of why I need to do so is unrelavant to this problem, long story short, I need it in some following process

```
 WITH RawDebug as 
(
  SELECT 
  STRUCT(DebugReason,DebugData) as Debug
  FROM `devicedata.Debug.T*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX="20180624"

),
RawGPS AS (        
       SELECT
          STRUCT(null as DebugReason,null as DebugData) as Debug
        FROM
          `devicedata.Gps.T*` AS g
         WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX="20180624"

)
select Debug
from RawDebug
UNION ALL
select Debug
from RawGPS
```

BigQuery says:

```
Error: Column 1 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRUCT<DebugReason INT64, DebugData STRING>, STRUCT<DebugReason INT64, DebugData INT64> at [18:1]
```

I can't figure out what's wrong...AND how to make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to explicitly specify STRUCT as below

```
WITH RawDebug AS 
(
  SELECT 
  STRUCT(DebugReason,DebugData) AS Debug
  FROM `devicedata.Debug.T*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX="20180624"
),
RawGPS AS (        
       SELECT
          STRUCT<DebugReason INT64, DebugData STRING>(NULL, NULL) AS Debug
        FROM
          `devicedata.Gps.T*` AS g
         WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX="20180624"
)
SELECT Debug
FROM RawDebug
UNION ALL
SELECT Debug
FROM RawGPS
```

Answer (score 7):

In one of the queries in the union, the `DebugData` field has type `STRING`, whereas in the other, it has type `INT64`. If you want a consistent type, you need to cast:

```
WITH RawDebug as 
(
  SELECT 
  STRUCT(DebugReason,DebugData) as Debug
  FROM `devicedata.Debug.T*`

),
RawGPS AS (        
       SELECT
          STRUCT(
            null as DebugReason,
            CAST(DebugData AS STRING) AS DebugData -- note the cast
          ) as Debug
        FROM
          `devicedata.Gps.T*` AS g

)
select Debug
from RawDebug
UNION ALL
select Debug
from RawGPS
```

This happens because the default type of `NULL` is `INT64`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. it makes sense to me that default type of NULL is INT64. However, your suggestion doesn't work for my case, where there is no "DebugData" in the Gps.T* tables, I need NULL to fake that column in order to do UNION.  Mikhall's answer solves the problem. But again, thanks for taking time looking at this!